# How to give root privilege to Windows Group

Tags: sudo, samba, active-directory

I have joined my Ubuntu server to Windows AD environment. Ubuntu server can successfully authenticate with the AD. I want to give Windows "domain admins" group to root privileges.
then I edited `/etc/sudoers` file and added

```
%TEST\\domain\ admins  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

like this (`test.com` is my domain name)
but when i try to run sudo commands it gives me

```
linuxadmin is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

(I added `linuxadmin` to domain admins group, My AD domain is running under windows 2016 and linux version is Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/756625/15811 is the(/a) way to set this up.

Comment: @Rinzwind - Thanks for your idea, it works. $ getent group | grep -i admin . It showed me - domain admins:x:50011: . Then I edited /etc/sudoers file as %domain\ admins  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following line to `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
%domaingroup ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

If you want the Windows Dom-Admin-Group to be sudoers, write down the real name of the group.

```
%domänen-admins ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

This worked well in our german Win2012R2/Debian environment.

You don't know the rigth name? Enter the shell-command

```
#>id
```

and you get the groups your currently loggedin user ist member of.